# What are the points I need to keep in mind while migrating my AngularJs 1.x project from angular material 1 to angular material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

My current project is in angularJs 1.5 and I'm using angular-material1. I'm looking into migrating to angular-material2. There's nothing about it in angular-material2 docs.

Comment: I would imagine it would be similar to any other mixing of Angular 1 and 2 components. Check out http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html Seems like it might be worth just upgrading to Angular 4 if your project isn't too big though.

Comment: It's actually quite big.